# Repeatedly execute python script over files in folder arranged in order of date

Tags: python, batch-file

I have huge collection of files stored in folder. I need to execute same python script to each of the file pair and output the result in txt or excel file. How can I automate the process python or batch script?
    Eg. Files inside Folder

```
ap.hdf5
sta.hdf5
ap_20150909_154518_00.hdf5
sta_20150909_154518_00.hdf5
ap_20150909_154530_00.hdf5
sta_20150909_154530_00.hdf5
ap_20150909_154541_00.hdf5
sta_20150909_154541_00.hdf5
```

These files are arranged based on data modified. I need to execute same python script to each of the pair and output result in text file.
Eg.

```
python result.py ap.hdf5 sta.hdf5
python result.py ap_20150909_154518_00.hdf5 sta_20150909_154518_00.hdf5
```

How can I create a batch file that could automate the process?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
Files inside Folder slightly different.

```
ap.hdf5
sta.hdf5
ap_20150909_154518_00.hdf5
sta_20150909_154524_00.hdf5
ap_20150909_154530_00.hdf5
sta_20150909_154536_00.hdf5
ap_20150909_154541_00.hdf5
sta_20150909_154547_00.hdf5
```

Here, Sta file is recorded at few second after AP.hdf5

Comment: The best and fastest solution would be to process all the files inside the python code. Is there any reason you don't want it?

Comment: If you're on a Unix-like system the `glob` module will be very helpful in building a list of pairs of related files, but it's not that hard to do it just using `os` functions.

Comment: @wOxxOm I can't because there files are created during experiment time. I have _result.py_ script which I need to run on  each of these files one after other.

Comment: I answered and only later saw your comment. Are the files fixed when you run result.py over them or are more files created at the same time (do you create the files first or in parallel to running result.py)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really do not want to modify `result.py` to do this, you could use the following approach:

```
import subprocess
import glob
import os.path

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    # ap files sorted by modified order
    files = sorted(glob.glob(r'ap*.hdf5'), key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))

    for ap in files:
        path, filename = os.path.split(ap)
        sta = os.path.join(path, 'sta{}'.format(filename[2:]))

        # Do we have an ap/sta pair?
        if os.path.exists(sta):
            # Launch the Python script with the required parameters
            p = subprocess.Popen(['python.exe', 'result.py', ap, sta], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            out, err = p.communicate()
            # Write stdout to a file and stderr to the screen
            f_output.write(out)
            print err
        else:
            print '{} is missing'.format(sta)
```

This will run your Python script for each `ap sta` file pair in date modified order, and write any output from the script to `output.txt`

**Update** - based on the updated question, the following script will pair the `ap` and `sta` files based on the file names. It will stop if a suitable pair is not found:

```
import subprocess
import glob
import os.path
import itertools

def sort_by_ending(filename):
    filename = os.path.split(filename)[1]
    if '_' in filename:
        return filename.split('_')[1:]
    else:
        return [filename]

folder = r'c:\test'

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    # ap and sta files sorted by filename ending
    files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, 'ap*.hdf5')) + glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, 'sta*.hdf5')), key=sort_by_ending)

    for ap, sta in itertools.izip(*[iter(files)]*2):
        print "'{}' and '{}'".format(os.path.split(ap)[1], os.path.split(sta)[1])
        # Do we have an ap/sta pair?
        if os.path.split(ap)[1].startswith('ap') and os.path.split(sta)[1].startswith('sta'):
            # Launch the Python script with the required parameters
            p = subprocess.Popen(['python.exe', 'result.py', ap, sta], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            out, err = p.communicate()
            # Write stdout to a file and stderr to the screen
            f_output.write(out)
            print err
        else:
            print '{} is missing'.format(sta)
            break
```

For your given file name examples, this will print the following output:

```
'ap_20150909_154518_00.hdf5' and 'sta_20150909_154524_00.hdf5'

'ap_20150909_154530_00.hdf5' and 'sta_20150909_154536_00.hdf5'

'ap_20150909_154541_00.hdf5' and 'sta_20150909_154547_00.hdf5'

'ap.hdf5' and 'sta.hdf5'
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Martin. Really grateful

Comment: hi Martin, what changes to make if the STA filename doesn't match exactly with AP. Eg. in the edit section.

Comment: I suppose the question is what do you regard as matching? What if two ap files are made within seconds of each other?

Comment: For my case, Two AP files are never created earlier than STA. During one measurement, AP is created first and with certain delay of few seconds its STA pair is created. After next measurement same process is repeated. I slightly changed the question because, your answer works but with the edited filename, it gives error the STA pair is missing.

Comment: Hi Martin, ur updated script only process the AP*.hdf5 and STA_*.hdf5 with same ending and leaves other whose ending doesn't match. From my experiment  after execution always AP and STA pair is generated. After arranging AP  and STA file based on its created then isn't it possible to process 1st two(AP-STA) pair... then next 2(AP-STA pair) and so on.

Comment: It works for the examples you have given. I have added a print statement and have displayed the output I get.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [glob module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to get a list of files starting with *ap*. Then you can change *ap* to *sta* to get the name of the paired file (assuming that there is always a pair of files). When you have this you can process them (as you did before).

```
import glob
# iterate over all files starting with ap and ending in .hdf5
for file_a in glob.iglob("ap*.hdf5"):
    # replace the beginning of the filename with sta
    file_b = "sta" + file_a[2:]

    # do your processing (result.py) using file_a and file_b as your pair
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob, os

ap_files = glob.glob("outdir/ap*.hdf5") #use glob to get ap files
for ap_file in ap_files:   #walk through the ap file names
  basename = os.path.basename(ap_file)  #split of the base name
  sta_file = "outdir/" + basename.replace("ap","sta",1) #make the sta name
  dothingsto(ap_file, sta_file)  #do whatever you wish to the two files
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.